# Cambiar color de barras segun su valor en ng2charts (ANGULAR)

Tags: angular

estoy trabajando en una grafica en angular 14, utilizando ng2charts, donde tengo mis valores en un array que se despliega en la grafica

Array con data:

```
  public chartData: ChartDataset[] = [
{data: [], label: 'Heart Rate Value'}
```

Despues tengo una funcion que me llena ese array con informacion que trae la api, e intento poner el fondo azul de cada barra si el valor esta entre 60 y 150, pero al poner la condicion toda la grafica se me pone azul, en vez de que se me pongan en azul nadamas las columnas que cumplan con la condicion

```
getData(){
this.sub = this.http.get<hearRateValues[]>(this.dashboardUrl)
.subscribe((data: hearRateValues[]) => {
  data.map((x) => {
    this.chartData[0].data.push(x.heartRate);
    this.labels.push(x.Hora);
    this.dateArray.push(x.Fecha);
    this.hourArray.push(x.Hora);

    if(x.heartRate > 59 && x.heartRate < 151) {
      this.chartData[0].backgroundColor  = 'blue';
    }

  })
  console.log(this.chartData);
  this.loadData = true;
 
});
```

html:

```
  <!--Div de la grafica-->
<div class="graph">
    <p class="titleGraph"> {{heartRateTitle}}</p>
    <p class="titleDate"> {{todayWithPipe}}</p>
    <div style="display: block">
        <canvas  *ngIf="this.loadData"  baseChart height="110" 
          [datasets]="chartData"
          [options]="options"
          [labels]="labels"
          [type]="'bar'">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

como podria hacerle para que funcione?, intente con un forEach para acceder a cada valor pero no me funciono., gracias

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola que tal!, tuve la misma inquietud por realizar algo similar, te explico lo que hice yo.
Antes que nada las versiones que yo ocupe fueron estas:

```
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",
"ng2-charts": "^2.4.0",
```

Después mi inquietud era ir comparando posición A contra la posición B de mis 2 series, esto con respecto al index correspondiente y de ahí colocar el color en especifico de la siguiente manera:

1. Si mi serie A en la posición 1 su valor es 19 y con mi serie B en la
   posición 1 es menor, este tomara 1 color en especifico, ejemplo rojo
   y fuese asignando a la serie B.
2. Para el segundo caso si mi posición 1 de la serie B es igual a la
   serie A, ejemplo: A = 19 y B = 19, este por ejemplo fuese color
   naranja, y lo mismo es asignado a la serie B.
3. Para el ultimo caso, si en la posición 1 vale 30 de la serie B y en
   la serie A vale 19, este en automático cambie el color a verde
   indicado que ha sobrepasado al valor del la serie A.

Todo lo anterior descrito se cumple con esta función:

```
getBarColor(data: any, dataIndex: any) {
  // Obtiene los valores de la serie de datos
    const values = data.dataset.data;
  // Compara los valores de las dos series de datos para definir el color de la barra
      if (values[dataIndex] === this.series1[dataIndex]) {
        return '#f2dead';
      } else if (values[dataIndex] > this.series1[dataIndex]) {
        return '#98FF98';
      }
      else if (values[dataIndex] < this.series1[dataIndex]) {
        return 'red';
      }
      else {
        return 'blue';
      }
  }
```

Y para hacer uso de esta función es como normalmente se cambia el color con la propiedad `backgroundColor`, haciendo uso así :

```
{
  data: this.series2,
  label: 'Real',
  backgroundColor: (data: any) => this.getBarColor(data, data.dataIndex) //Como nota debe de tener como referencia alguna de sus 2 series para comparala como fue mi caso yo hice uso de que this.serie1 era mi valor de referencia para compararlo y this.serie2 mi valor y/o variable de datos admitidos
}
```

En HTML:

```
<div style="display: block">
  <canvas baseChart
          [datasets]="barlineData"
          [labels]="barlineLabel"
          [options]="barOptions"
          [legend]="barLineChartLegend"
          [chartType]="barType"></canvas>
</div>
```

Para ts:

```
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { SingleDataSet, Label, monkeyPatchChartJsLegend, monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip, Color } from 'ng2-charts';
//Demas importaciones

series1 = [17, 17, 25];
  series2 = [16, 17, 37];
  public barType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barLineChartLegend = true;

  getBarColor(data: any, dataIndex: any) {
  // Obtiene los valores de la serie de datos
    const values = data.dataset.data;
  // Compara los valores de las dos series de datos para definir el color de la barra
      if (values[dataIndex] === this.series1[dataIndex]) {
        return '#f2dead';
      } else if (values[dataIndex] > this.series1[dataIndex]) {
        return '#98FF98';
      }
      else if (values[dataIndex] < this.series1[dataIndex]) {
        return 'red';
      }
      else {
        return 'blue';
      }
  }
  
  public barOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
        },
        stacked: false        
      }],
      yAxes: [{

        gridLines: {
          display: true,
        },
        stacked: false
      }]
    },   
    plugins: {
      
      labels: {
        render: 'value', // renderizar solo el valor de la barra
        fontColor: '#fff', // color del texto
        fontSize: 0, // tamaño de la fuente
        precision: 0, // número de decimales a mostrar
        display: false // deshabilitar la visualización de etiquetas
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: true, // deshabilitar la leyenda
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  public barlineLabel: Label[] = ['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3'];

  public barlineData: Array<any> = [
    {
      data: this.series1,
      label: 'Presupuesto',
      backgroundColor: '#f7b0c1'
    },
    {
      data: this.series2,
      label: 'Real',
      backgroundColor: (data: any) => this.getBarColor(data, data.dataIndex)
    },
  ];
```

Adjunto un ejemplo con los datos de arriba.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]